# Limit of sequence of random variables still $G$-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose I have a sequence of random variables $Y_n \in L^2$ each of which is measurable w.r.t. some $\sigma$-algebra G. If I know that $Y_n$ converge almost surely to $Y$ and that the norms $||Y_n - Y_{n+1}||_2$ converge to $0$, do I know that $Y$ will also be $G$-measurable?

This is one of these cases where it seems intuitively clear, but I don't have a rigorous argument.

Answer (score 0):

> Hint:  $\, \liminf Y_n$ is $G$-measurable

If the random variable converges to some $Y$, then we must have $\liminf Y_n = \limsup Y_n = Y$. As $\liminf Y_n$ is a measurable random variable w.r.t. the $\sigma$-algebra $G$, then the limiting random variable remains measurable.

Comment: Thank you!

I was unaware of this fact. This happens when one learns probability without learning proper measure theory first...